# Why does increasing the sample rate with SoundForge make the pitch go way up?

Tags: sample-rate

I have a  problem. I have to increase the sample rate to 44.100. But when I do pitch goes way up and the track plays faster! HELP
Using SoundForge

Answer (score 1):

All you are doing here is changing the project sampling rate. Remember, all the audio files you are using will remain at their original sampling rate. It's not clear exactly what the original sampling rate is but you need to complete the project at the original sampling rate and then output or render at the desired sampling rate.

The other option is to render at your original sampling rate and then use an external sampling rate converter.

Typical tools for this are r8brain - this is a very popular sample rate converter.

Should you decide you want to perform the sampling rate conversion inside of Soundforge, use the PROCESS>RESAMPLE function. Just remember to change the project sampling rate to match.

Comment: I don't think it's a 48/44 issue, maybe they're starting at way lower, 22 or so… but your theory is otherwise absolutely sound. +1

Comment: good point. I will edit.